# Positionning particle in node

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Using cocos2d, I'm trying to replace a sprite (item in my code) with a particle system. This code is placed in my board class. This one works:

```
    // Draw the particles 
    CCParticleSystem *particles = [[CCParticleSystem alloc] initWithDictionary:_popParticles];
    particles.position = ccpSub(item.position,ccp(160,160));
    particles.autoRemoveOnFinish = TRUE;
    [self addChild:particles];
```

This one doesn't:

```
    // Draw the particles 
    CCParticleSystem *particles = [[CCParticleSystem alloc] initWithDictionary:_popParticles];
    particles.position = item.position;
    particles.autoRemoveOnFinish = TRUE;
    [self addChild:particles];
```

I tried player with this but without success:

```
    particles.positionType = CCPositionTypeMake(CCPositionUnitUIPoints, CCPositionUnitUIPoints, CCPositionReferenceCornerBottomLeft);
```

My board is a 320x320 points CCSprite with anchor point set at 0.5, 0.5

When I log my item.position value, I get something relative to the bottom left corner of my board (from 30,30 to 290,290)

Is using ccpSub the correct way ?

[image: Hierarchy of my objects in Spritebuilder]

Comment: What does 'not work' mean exactly ? What is self.positionType ? is  `onEnter` completed ? what is `self.contentSizeInPoints` ?

Comment: 'not work ' means the position of the particles does not match the position of the 'item object' I want to replace (it's 160px,160px on the top right of the item position). onEnter is completed, self.contentSizeInPoints={0, 0}. I don't know how to log self.positionType :(

Comment: ok, then may you want to add particles to 'item' and not board (self) ? i am assuming it derives for a CCNode.

Comment: 'item' is a CCSprite, child of a CCPhysicsNode contained in a CCNode with custom class Board

Comment: It seems I can't add my particles to 'item' because I'm destroying the object the next line ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you destroy a node you also destroy all of it's children nodes, you said you add your particle to 'item' then you destroy that 'item', which means you have no particle anymore.